Two batteries charging one capacitor
I'm little stuck on this problem.
Here we have two different resistors and two batteries of same voltage. When the switch S is closed and assuming steady state, I think that the voltage around the capacitor will be zero. Because the two positive terminals of the batteries cancel each other's voltage, and the negative terminals have zero potential as far as I understand.
Perhaps I'm missing something. Tried to simulate this circuit in Falstad simulator, and got actually that the voltage around the capacitor is ε. But I can't agree with that.


Welcome! "batteries cancel each other's voltage" Please explain how.

After the gate S, at the point before capacitor C we should have the potential of: ε-ε=0

@sharkbait50 Nothing in the circuit indicates that. Which is why we ask why you think so.

https://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-we-connect-two-identical-cells-in-parallel-but-with-opposite-polarities-Do-the-EMFs-cancel-out-like-in-a-series

In the link to quora.com, they say that it should cancel. What do I miss here?

The polarity. Name your bottom horizontal node ground to make it easier for you. Then write the voltage in every node before the switch is closed.

Let's simplify the situation...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now let's show the situation where they'd "cancel out" - note that the positive terminals are connected and pointing towards each other, while the negative terminals are pointing away. The voltmeter is effectively an open circuit (i.e: no current flows through it / the wires connecting to the meter are not connected to each other), and it's position in the circuit is what matters here.

simulate this circuit

Thanks, now it makes sense. It's a tricky problem, though

Falstad simulation is right. I agree with that.
There is nothing in the circuit why capacitor voltage would be 0. It will equal to battery voltage.
